# Login failed for user 'sa'. in connection string

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I'm getting the following error:

> Login failed for user 'sa'

When I try to connect server by setting value through a string variable:

```
private SqlConnection getDbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source="+dbname+";Initial Catalog="+catname+";User Id=sa;Password=sa;Integrated Security=false");
```

But when I use the normal connection string with no string variable it works well:

```
private SqlConnection getDbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Ali-pc\\;Initial Catalog=master;User Id=sa;Password=sa;Integrated Security=false");
```

Comment: Username and password is wrong ?

Comment: Did you try to debug, and see that the values are truely what you think they are ?

Comment: Where do you set the 'dbname ' and 'catname' variables?

Comment: If you stick a break point on that line and hover your cursor over the variables are they the same as the values in the purely hard code string?

Comment: sa? You know that's a really **really** bad idea, right? Even for testing code.

Comment: Print out the parsed connection string and spot the difference

Comment: @Joel We use sa for every database query in our applications. Always. Everytime. I'm so happy that I leave this company soon :-)

Comment: @dkson, About half the companies I've worked at have done that, passwords in clear text too ;)

Comment: @Paulie And, obviously, same logins/passwords on all customers :)

Answer (score 2):

put your connectionstring in web.config file as I show below

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Test" connectionString="data source=Harsh; Initial Catalog=Test ; user Id=sa; password=sa123;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Above "Test" is  connectionstringname,you can write your datasource name.Mine is Harsh,so changed it according to yours.Give your database name in inital catalog.

And then put this code in your code behind page load event

```
SqlConnection con = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ToString());
```

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the server name and the database name (in the *dbname* and *catname* variables) are just wrong?

BTW, i would recommend using the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dce36088.aspx) class.

```
var sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder() { InitialCatalog = catname,
                                            DataSource = dbname,
                                            UserID = "sa",
                                            Password = "sa" };

var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(sb.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: no there are right i checked already thats why i post this problem

Comment: did you compare the two connection string while debugging?