# login failed for user 'sa'.

Tags: c#, sql-server

I try to connect to sql-server by calling this class:

```
class DataCon
{
    public static SqlConnection Connection { get; private set; }

    public static void connectDB(string ip, string dbName, string user, string pw)
    {
        string connectionSt = "Server="+ip+";Database="+dbName+";User Id="+user+";Password="+pw+";";
        ConnectToSql(connectionSt);
    }

    private static void ConnectToSql(string connectionSt) {
        Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionSt);
        Connection.Open();
    }

    public static void connectDB(string ip, string dbName)
    {
        string connectionSt = "Server="+ip+";Database="+dbName+";Trusted_Connection=True;";
        ConnectToSql(connectionSt);
    }
}
```

It work when using Windows Authentication but the Server Authentication that give login failed for user 'sa'.

On Sql server management studio I could login successfully with both Windows and Server Authentication with 'sa'.

This is the form I work with:

```
        private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string dbsName = "dbsStudent";
            string ip = "localhost";
            string user = txtUser.Text;
            string pw = txtUser.Text;

            if (cbAuthentication.SelectedIndex == 0)
                DataCon.connectDB(ip,dbsName);
            else
                DataCon.connectDB(ip,dbsName,user,pw);
            this.Hide();
            new ViewSt().Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the thumb down at all. I said that I could login to management studio with that 'sa' user but not in C#.......

Comment: your question is in this links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567939/login-failed-for-user-c-sharp-with-sqlconnection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636511/login-failed-for-user-sa-in-connection-string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016681/login-failed-for-user-sa-at-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: I know you going to point to those two question that I've already read..... It's not the same problem, dude

Answer (score 0):

If your password contains special chars like ';', your connection string will be incorrect.

Consider using SqlConnectionStringBuilder class to build connection string as described on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look about [Integrated Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Integrated Security When false, User ID and Password are specified in
>   the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are
>   used for authentication. Recognized values are true, false, yes, no,
>   and sspi (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true. If User
>   ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true,
>   the User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will
>   be used.

So probably if you want to use user "sa" to log in to a DB you should take a look about setting Integrated security to false in your connection string and try to work it out :)

If you have any question leave me a comment here.